# Combine dynamically generated PDF into a single PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I have a page where I have individual links to dynamically create individual PDF files using TCPDF and it is working without any problem.

My challenge is that I now want to provide a link which when clicked, creates a single PDF file that combines all the individual PDF reports into one.

can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: if you realy want to use php, use fpdi for it ... create a new pdf with x pages and fill each pages with the page of the single pdfs see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418945/tcpdf-start-with-existing-pdf-document

Comment: you can user pdftk for that https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: Thanks @Donald123. I will be trying it out soon and give feedback. Disha, thank you too. However I want to do it in php, not using a standalone application